# How to remove an empty list from a list (Java)

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have searched for this but it's in other languages like Python or R (?).
I have lists inside a list and I would like to remove the empty list.
For example:

> [ [abc,def], [ghi], [], [], [jkl, mno]]

I would like:

> [ [abc,def], [ghi], [jkl, mno]]

How do I remove empty list from a list?
Thanks!

Comment: I would try `list.removeAll(new ArrayList());`

Comment: @Kon nope it didn't work

Comment: Why would null or "" match an empty list? You seem to have a very strange and wrong idea of what is going on here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try this as well:

```
list.removeIf(p -> p.isEmpty());
```

Comment: This is a much better choice than the accepted answer, it's much more obvious what the intent is.

Comment: However, if you have this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31196977/4086836], this answer will return a NullPointerException

Comment: Can also be written like this: `list.removeIf(List::isEmpty);`

Answer (score 12):

You could use:

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: Can you go a bit in detail and explain what is going on in there?

Comment: or `.removeAll(Collections.singleton(Collections.emptyList())`

Answer (score 11):

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(new ArrayList<>()));
```

The code above works fine for many cases but it's dependent on the *equals* method implementation of the List in the list so if you have something like the code below it will fail.

```
public class AnotherList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof AnotherList && super.equals(o);
    }
}

List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Arrays.asList("abc", "def"));
list.add(Arrays.asList("ghi"));
list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
list.add(new AnotherList());
list.add(null);
list.add(Arrays.asList("jkl", "mno"));
```

A solution is:

```
list.removeIf(x -> x != null && x.isEmpty());
```

If you have no worry about a different implementation of *equals* method you can use the other solution.

Comment: The contract of `java.util.List` actually specifies the precise behavior of `equals` in order to guarantee that this problem does not occur. Of course, this aspect of the contract cannot be enforced by the compiler; nonetheless, the problem in your example is that `AnotherList` violates [the Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). That defect should be fixed, rather than worked around; or, failing that, instances of it shouldn't be used when a `List` or `ArrayList` is expected.